# SSL certificate error в Python 3.8 (Debian). Как отключить проверку сертификата?

Tags: python, debian, бот, ssl

Нашел много инфы по этому поводу, но тем не менее не могу понять как решить это в коде (не мой). Этот же самый код прекрасно работает на маке, а вот в дебиане получается:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 986, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1046, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1076, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncprawcore/requestor.py", line 64, in request
    return await self._http.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 535, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 542, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 907, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1206, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 988, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host www.reddit.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/smb/cyberzhmyh/main.py", line 82, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 612, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/mnt/smb/cyberzhmyh/main.py", line 28, in main
    item = await memes_submissions.__anext__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpraw/models/listing/generator.py", line 63, in __anext__
    await self._next_batch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpraw/models/listing/generator.py", line 73, in _next_batch
    self._listing = await self._reddit.get(self.url, params=self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpraw/reddit.py", line 661, in get
    return await self._objectify_request(method="GET", params=params, path=path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpraw/reddit.py", line 765, in _objectify_request
    await self.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpraw/reddit.py", line 967, in request
    return await self._core.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncprawcore/sessions.py", line 370, in request
    return await self._request_with_retries(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncprawcore/sessions.py", line 270, in _request_with_retries
    response, saved_exception = await self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncprawcore/sessions.py", line 187, in _make_request
    response = await self._rate_limiter.call(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncprawcore/rate_limit.py", line 34, in call
    kwargs["headers"] = await set_header_callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncprawcore/sessions.py", line 322, in _set_header_callback
    await self._authorizer.refresh()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncprawcore/auth.py", line 371, in refresh
    await self._request_token(grant_type="client_credentials", **additional_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncprawcore/auth.py", line 153, in _request_token
    response = await self._authenticator._post(url, **data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncprawcore/auth.py", line 33, in _post
    response = await self._requestor.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncprawcore/requestor.py", line 68, in request
    raise RequestException(exc, args, kwargs)
asyncprawcore.exceptions.RequestException: error with request Cannot connect to host www.reddit.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')]
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0xb64a6088>
```

Бот в двух скриптах - config.py и main.py

**config.py**

```
import asyncpraw

vk_login = "+375447335***"
vk_password = "idkfa1996Lam***"
vk_group_id = -153615780
vk_group_message = ""

reddit_bot = asyncpraw.Reddit(client_id='QQYRRX7_q_o6Lw',
                              client_secret='5mranARRhbF50ZL9hIdDFyeibANUvA',
                              user_agent='thulebot/0.0.1')
SUBREDDIT = 'memes'
SUBREDDITS = ["memes", "memes"]
reddit_time_filter = "day"

sleep_time = 3600
POST_LIMIT = 1
image_formats = ["jpg", "png", "bmp"]
group_message = "Cyberzhmyh"
copyright_enable = True
copyright_url = "https://www.reddit.com/"

service_key = "18c3f52b18c3f52b18c3f52ba818b9de1b118c318c3f52b7959c07b55a5d6eae4762b57"
secure_key = "Z1cEzGn3EDSTbrhYl5Vm"
app_id = "8006448"
```

**main.py**

```
import asyncio
import os
import random
import ssl
import urllib.request
from datetime import datetime

import vk_api
from vk_api import VkUpload

import config

s=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
s.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE


reddit_bot = config.reddit_bot
title_array = []

while True:
    try:
        async def main():
            while True:
                print("Bot target url: r/memes")
                print(f"Group: {config.group_message}")
                memes_submissions = await reddit_bot.subreddit(random.choice(config.SUBREDDITS))
                memes_submissions = memes_submissions.new(limit=config.POST_LIMIT)
                item = await memes_submissions.__anext__()
                if item.title not in title_array:
                    print("Pic found...")
                    if item.url[-3:] in config.image_formats:
                        title_array.append(item.title)
                        urllib.request.urlretrieve(item.url, f"image.{item.url[-3:]}")
                        print("Pic downloaded...")
                        print(os.path.abspath(f"image.{item.url[-3:]}"))

                        vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(config.vk_login, config.vk_password)
                        vk_session.http.headers[
                            'User-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0'
                        vk_session.auth()
                        vk = vk_session.get_api()
                        upload = VkUpload(vk_session)

                        picture = os.path.abspath(f"image.{item.url[-3:]}")
                        picture_upload = upload.photo_wall(picture)

                        attachment = ','.join('photo{owner_id}_{id}'.format(**item) for item in picture_upload)

                        if config.copyright_enable:
                            copyright_link = str(config.copyright_url) + str(item)
                            posting = vk_session.method('wall.post', {
                                'owner_id': config.vk_group_id,
                                'from_group': 1,
                                'message': config.vk_group_message,
                                'attachment': attachment,
                                'copyright': copyright_link
                            })
                        else:
                            posting = vk_session.method('wall.post', {
                                'owner_id': config.vk_group_id,
                                'from_group': 1,
                                'message': config.vk_group_message,
                                'attachment': attachment
                            })
                        now = datetime.now()
                        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                        print("POST PUBLISHED SUCCESSFULLY AT", current_time)
                        os.remove(picture)
                        await asyncio.sleep(config.sleep_time)
                    else:
                        print("ERROR: UNKNOWN FORMAT\n-JOB IS DONE-\n")
                        await asyncio.sleep(config.sleep_time)
                else:
                    print("DUBLICATE DETECTED")
                    print("-JOB IS DONE-\n")
                    await asyncio.sleep(config.sleep_time)
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Во-первых, переведите вопрос на русский язык. Во-вторых, нужно не бездумно отключать какие попало проверки, а разобраться, почему конкретно проверка сертификата провалилась, и решать причину, а не затыкать симптом

Comment: Перевел на русский, разобраться не могу ибо не пишу на питоне. Суть моего вопроса в том, чтобы заставить код работать, с отключенным ssl либо нет это не имеет значения. Но могу предположить что отключить проще. Не стоит задача иметь защищенное соединение

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит как будто у вас устаревший пакет корневых сертификатов.
Выполните от суперпользователя:

```
apt update
apt upgrade -y ca-certificates
```

Comment: Попробую и отпишу, получилось или нет

Comment: Обновил, все равно вижу ту же ошибку